# Why sizeof('\n') and sizeof(char) not equal?

Tags: c

I've tested `sizeof('\n')` is 4, but if when it is assigned to a char variable, then it occupies 1 byte of memory.

```
char enter = '\n';
sizeof(enter); // 1
```

What are their sizes different?

Comment: The type of `'\n'` is `int`, I'm sure there are many duplicates in SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `'\n'` is `int`, therefore `sizeof('\n')` equals `sizeof(int)`; on the other hand, `sizeof(char)` always equals 1.